# The package *** is accessible from more than one module

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, graalvm

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.4.3 on Ubuntu 19.10 with Maven 3.6.3 and GraalVM graalvm-ce-java11-20.0.0.
The static analysis of my java project gives me this error:

```
The package org.graalvm.polyglot is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, org.graalvm.sdk
```

I don't know which package does `<unnamed>` refer to and where to look to solve the "double import" problem.

N.B.: this error does no happen if I compile my project directly using `mvn` from terminal, but this actually seems to be a bug of the javac compiler, see [this issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1000).

**UPDATE**
The above error is raised by Visual Studio Code in each source file where I import something from `org.graalvm.polyglot` (e.g., `import org.graalvm.polyglot.Value;`) and my `$CLASSPATH` variable is currently empty.

**UPDATE**
Currently inside `pom.xml` I have

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.graalvm.truffle</groupId>
  <artifactId>truffle-api</artifactId>
  <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
</dependency>-->
```

By trial and errors I hav found that I need to remove *both* dependencies in order to get rid of the error above, but in this way I get an import error for anything inside `com.oracle.truffle` (e.g., `The import com.oracle.truffle.api cannot be resolved`)

**UPDATE**:
Running `mvn clean package install -DskipTests` from terminal compiles the project without any complaint.

Comment: The unnamed modules is basically everything that's on the (legacy) classpath. So something is adding the `org.graalvm.polyglot` package to *both* the module-path **and** the classpath.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `CLASSPATH` is not used in Maven. I don't know how Maven handles modules as dependencies (haven't used it in a while), but check how polyglot is declared as a dependency. Maybe it slipped in as a transitive dependency somewhere as well and one of those needs excluding.

Comment: Thank you @JoachimSauer for you suggestions, unfortunately I'm completely new to Java and I don't know where to to look. I've updated my question with some additional info.

Comment: Looks like it is related to bug https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10226